# Qt Creator 2.7 add new disabled

Tags: qt-creator

I'm sitting in Ubuntu 12.04 with Qt Creator v2.7 (tried new one aswell, 2.8 beta) and when I create a Non-Qt Project / Plain C++ Project (CMake Build) all seems well. But when I right-click on the project to Add New, that option is disabled. So is Add Existing Files..., New Subproject and Add Library.

Am I missing something obvious? I think I've been through pretty much all of the menus but I can't find anything seemingly related to this issue.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't use `cmake`, but if I remember this correctly you have to add the file/s in `CMakeLists.txt` and this makes sense because you explicitly choosing `cmake` over the internal building system.

Comment: You are correct! It seems I have not really understood what it means to use cmake in Qt Creator. Now only to figure out how to set your response to an answer.

Comment: I have added a complete answer, glad you solved this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because you have to add the file/s in `CMakeLists.txt` and this makes sense because you explicitly choosing `cmake` over the internal building system.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the file to the `CMakeLists.txt` file.

   Note: If you added another file while working on the same project, that new `.cpp` file would already be added in the same folder structure as your current project. In that case, no changes to `CMakeLists.txt` are required.
2. Now simply, right click on the project entry and click on "Run CMake". This will automatically add the newly created `.cpp` file to the project structure and it will be shown in the project outline view.